# Most popular items for videos records as zero

Tags: analytics

Most popular items works for all my documents.  It records a zero for all the videos.  They are either mp4 or wmv.  Any ideas why?

Thank you,
Maria

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure these services are running :

Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Usage Data Import

Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Usage Data Processing

There seems to be an issue with Popular Items not working properly when Office Web Apps server hasn't been deployed. It is unofficially reported as a fix by a few people, however I have yet to find any official documentation to support this other than the sites below...

Sources :

http://nickhurstblog.com/2013/04/30/library-most-popular-items-not-working/

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/71066e40-87cd-4a6b-88fd-d78daa1b858f/most-popular-items-not-working-for-document-libraries

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/77ea47c3-72f8-49d9-b328-2f281a6f7d56/most-popular-items-are-not-populating-on-lists-and-libraries?forum=sharepointgeneral

Comment: Thanks for the response.  We have the services running.  We have not installed Office Web Apps

Answer (score 0):

Check the IIS log - what's the status code for the hits for the video files?  If it's a redirect (e.g. 301 or 302), that's the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that views of mp4 and wmv files aren't counted as documents.  Do you see the mp4 and wmv files in the hits reports?

If you have the ability to define the list of file types that are counted as documents, simply add mp4 and wmv to the list.  If you aren't able to do this in SharePoint, there are a handful of commercial web analytics software products that can do this.  My clients use Angelfish Software for this exact scenario.